# Why did I fail this review audit when the post is clearly a comment?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

The question is straightforward and pertains to a user's recent upgrade of the Spotify Windows client. It was well-received and gathered a reasonable number of answers, comments and views.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7466717

The first person to answer was a developer at Spotify, who responded with:

> I'm a developer at Spotify. We know that there are some regressions in
>   the new client, especially regarding remote control. I'll ask my
>   colleagues about this issue, also can you please confirm that this
>   problem is on Windows?

This does not feel like an acceptable answer on Stack Overflow, despite the number of votes (+8). It's also attracted one low quality moderation comment from a user just 2 days ago - I'd be intrigued to know whether this question was in the test queue at the time of that user's review or not.

I wanted to vote to delete this answer as being better suited to a comment - but the system caught me first.

I'm currently temp review banned as a result of this.

Comment: No downvotes at the time meant it was eligible for the "Looks Good" vote.  It's absolutely not an answer, and the only reason I can guess why it had 8 upvotes is that people in the Spotify tag will upvote anything?  `*shrug*  It looks like it might have gone through the Low Quality Review queue based on the comments, I'll dig through the review history and see how it got voted on.

Comment: Incorporating the comments into the answer does make it an answer ("[The fix] will be shipped in the next update of the desktop client"), so maybe that's where the upvotes come from.  I agree with you that _as it stands_ it is not an answer.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables its a pseudo-authorative response (not an answer) from an individual claiming affiliation with the company that would be an appropriate note in a bug report... so it may be useful to people... but no, it isn't an answer.

Comment: I just failed a similar audit too. An 'I disagree' button would be nice, next to the 'I understand' one.

Comment: Found it:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7414181.

Comment: And really, to top it all off, a 10K+ user really should know better to post that as a comment than an answer.  In short, you got screwed :P

Comment: A moderator has just deleted the answer - I can't see it anymore. Thanks for your digging, @LittleBobbyTables ! :)

Comment: And here's a feature request over on MSE: [Don't include posts in known good when a plurality of reviews on the post recommend deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252026/213963) that should try to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: It did have a system-generated moderator attention flag on it to get us to look at it because of the disputed review, which we simply hadn't processed yet. That should have been enough to get it deleted, but it got stuck in the middle of a bunch of other noisy flags and we didn't get to it in a timely manner.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on SU  instead ? in fact all Autohotkey questions ?

Comment: @Shekhar Hmm...well technically [tag:AutoHotKey] uses a [very simple bespoke scripting language](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/9038-what-programming-language-does-autohotkey-use/) so seems relevant to SO imo. As for the [tag:spotify] tag that seems too board for SO imo.

Comment: This is just a bad audit, I have been temp banned a couple of times due to these bad audits as well and it is annoying

Comment: @Lankymart agreed, but the scripting is more to do with configuration and behavior of one machine and less to do with writing an application that somebody else uses.

Comment: @Shekhar No that is exactly what it is. I could write a AHK script and give it to someone else to provide functionality I was using. It's not just configuration AHK is a very versatile scripting language.

Comment: @Lankymart well, in theory I could give my regedit file to somebody else too. I feel AHK in a gray area and  my personal take is that it should be on SU.

Comment: @Shekhar How is that even a fair comparison? Can you debug RegEdit? Is it advertised as a scripting language?  Does it have language elements like variables, operators, expressions, conditionals and functions? You are seriously undermining how powerful it actually is. These are all programming elements and as such belong on SO not SU it's that simple. If you wanted advice on installed AHK then by all means ask it on SU.

Comment: @Lankymart I can buy this argument I guess :)